# Where is Peach after I finished Super Mario Galaxy 1 or 2?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2, super-mario-galaxy

I finished the story in Super Mario Galaxy 1 and 2 and rescued Peach. I often play with my 5 year old daughter, who is very happy that Peach is safe again. However, she is nowhere to be seen! Even stranger, we still get letters from Peach that say that she is far away but so happy that Mario is coming to rescue her. But we already did!

Am I missing something? Is Peach anywhere to be found in the Observatory/Starship Mario?

This probably sounds like a silly question but my daughter would really like to see Peach so I hope that she is hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The letter text remains the same before and after the rescue. Peach is safe but far away again (in her castle). I don't think the letter speaks of "rescue" though.

Kudos to your daughter for appreciating the story line. I am huge Mario fan myself and also think in those terms. It makes the game more enjoyable.

Alas, I don't think there is a way to see Peach after rescuing her. I recommend you tell your daughter that Peach is safe in her castle since Bowser has been defeated (for a while). Mario is free to pursue a few remaining adventures after finishing his main task.

(I agree it would be great if Peach joined Mario as a character he could talk to after rescue. Nintendo really missed an opportunity here.)

Comment: Thank you! It's sad, but now at least we can stop looking.

Answer (score 6):

As already answered, Peach is, alas, safely out of view.

However, your daughter may be interested in a storyline wherein Mario, Peach, Rosalina, and a whole bunch of other characters make it back to the Mushroom Kingdom to race against each other in Mario Kart Wii.